# Unable to select a button using Selenium WebDriver in Java

Tags: java, selenium, automation

Trying to select a button from a collapsible area of a web page using Selenium WebDriver.  I'm very new to WebDriver, and am having issues figuring out how to get this particular little monster.

```
    <a href="#" class="btn new-fields-button" data-fields="&lt;div class='contributor-form form-inline form-nested'&gt; 
&lt;select id=&quot;video_item_contributors_attributes_39041920_role&quot; name=&quot;video_item[contributors_attributes]
[39041920][role]&quot;&gt;&lt;option value=&quot;Actor&quot;&gt;Actor&lt;/option&gt; &lt;option 
value=&quot;Director&quot;&gt;Director&lt;/option&gt; &lt;option value=&quot;Writer&quot;&gt;Writer&lt;/option&gt; 
&lt;option value=&quot;Producer&quot;&gt;Producer&lt;/option&gt;&lt;/select&gt; &lt;input class=&quot;input-small&quot; 
id=&quot;video_item_contributors_attributes_39041920_name&quot; name=&quot;video_item[contributors_attributes][39041920][name]&quot; 
placeholder=&quot;Name&quot; size=&quot;30&quot; type=&quot;text&quot; /&gt; &lt;a class='btn btn-danger delete-nested' 
data-destroy-id='destroy-contributor-toggle-'&gt; &lt;i class='ss-trash'&gt;&lt;/i&gt; &lt;/a&gt; &lt;/div&gt; " 
data-id="39041920"><i class="ss-plus"></i> Add Contributor</a>
```

That's the section of code (tried to break it up to be readable here) that describes the button that neds to be clicked, copied directly from Chrome's "Inspect Element" view.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ensure first that the `a` element is not within an iframe. If it is, you will have to switch context to the frame using `driver.switchTo().frame("frameName")`.

Then find something that is unique and consistent with the `a` element to be able to identify it. Some example xpath locators you can use are below.

For reference, read [XPath W3C Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) - it provides all the info you will ever need for working with xpaths.

By anchor text

```
By.xpath("//a[text()=' Add Contributor']")
```

Using the `class` value with xpath

```
By.xpath("//a[@class='btn new-fields-button']")
```

To do a partial match, you can use [`contains()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-contains)

```
By.xpath("//a[contains(@class,'new-fields-button')]")
```

You can also use multiple selectors, such as:

```
By.xpath("//a[contains(@class,'new-fields-button') and contains(text(),'Add Contributor')]")
```

Comment: By.xpath("//a[@class='btn new-fields-button']")  worked for me.  Thank you for that, and for the XPath reference so I can read up on that a bit.  Appreciate the help!

Comment: Additional question, related to this. Is there a way to use the third item you listed with a nth iteration, such that it will pick the third item that matches the requirement?

Comment: @mikecole79: Use `webDriver.findElements(xpath)`, this will return a `List` of `WebElement` that match the criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the info given, you could do an xpath search like this:

```
WebElement button = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@data-id='39041920']"));
```

No idea, if the data-id attribute is unique or not though, as you don't really tell much about your page in the question.

Comment: Another locator than can be used is `By.linkText(" Add Contributor")` - mind the space at the beginning, or use `By.partialLinkText()`.

Comment: Tried partialLinkText and it didn't work.  The data-id is not usable, as I'll be using the code to modify many different items, all stored on similar pages.  The data-id will be unique to each item, and therefore different every time I run the process in order to modify an asset.  I've never done anything with xpath before.  Would that method possibly work with a wildcard of some sort?

Comment: @mikecole79 - Added an answer with more details on xpath usage. Certainly ensure first that you switch to the right frame (if any).

Comment: @mikecole79: You can do a lot of different matches with an xpath expression, my point mostly was that until you tell us more about the layout of the page, how many other similar items there are, etc. it's pretty hard to say anything certain about what to use. Only simple match is `By.id("foobar")`, since id's have to be unique for proper HTML, but your button doesn't have an id, so cannot use that.